# Merge two different sql file to one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two .sql file for MySql database with same tables but different rows.

How can I make one .sql file with the datas of other two?

Comment: can you please add a bit more information to your post, I'm not sure what you mean by same tables but different rows.... do these sql files contain the data? the schema to the table? It would help if you post a bit more of information, and an example of what is in the sql files.

Comment: your request sounds a little bit sloppy. if you have two queries running in two different files and each query runs for the same table and simply returns a different data-set (due to different WHERE conditions) but with the same column-set you just need to put those queries together into the same file using the *UNION* clause. If you have a different column-set you can still use the *UNION* but you need to adjust the queries to make the column-set match. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

If your files contain data only (DML - SELECTs, INSERTs etc.), then you can join them simply via notepad. But both of files must contain the same table (the same columns)!

Comment: Theres is same rows in the two file. So when I want to importing this two files I get an error in phpmyadmin.